# Dockerfile maven with ARG

Tags: java, maven, docker

On my dockerfile, i try to run this command line

```
RUN mvn install -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/store -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
```

It doesn't work :(. I have this error

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.springframework:java-backend-bdd:0.1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 13, column 13

I can put anything on the arguments -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore or -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword, same error

I also try this command line

```
 RUN ["mvn", "install","-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/store", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password"]
```

How can i run maven with argument on Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 0):

Your first command should work fine. No need to split the run into an array of args.

However, did you copy the cert into the Docker container first? If the cert is in the repo, you'll need to add a line like

```
RUN mkdir /app/store
COPY /my/local/cert/store/ /app/store
```

This will copy the contents of your local cert store to the /app/store path in the docker container.